# How to fetch an array of images from firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to populate my SliderView with an array of images from firestore [see pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSXAM.jpg)

This is my first time working on firestore with array and SliderView so I'm not sure how to fetch it properly.
Here is my code

```
albumRV = findViewById(R.id.albumrv);
    packagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    AlbumAdapter albumAdapter = new AlbumAdapter(getApplicationContext(), packagesList);
    albumRV.setSliderAdapter(albumAdapter);
    albumRV.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM);
    albumRV.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.DEPTHTRANSFORMATION);
    albumRV.startAutoCycle();

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Destinations")
            .whereEqualTo("package_name", desName)
            .orderBy("package_images", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    List listImg = value.getDocumentChanges();
                    if (listImg.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(DestinationDetail.this, "NO RECYCLERVIEW", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                Log.d(TAG, documentChange.getDocument() + " => ");

                                packagesList.add(documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Packages.class));
                            }
                            albumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

And as for my adapter

```
public class AlbumAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<AlbumAdapter.Holder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Packages> packagesList;


public AlbumAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Packages> packagesList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.packagesList = packagesList;
}

@Override
public AlbumAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.images_single, parent, false);
    return new Holder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AlbumAdapter.Holder viewHolder, int position) {
    Packages packages = packagesList.get(position);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(packagesList.get(position).getPackage_images())
            .thumbnail(0.05f)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
            .into(viewHolder.img);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return packagesList.size();
}

public class Holder extends  SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder{
    ImageView img;

    public Holder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
    }
}
```

}

**Edited:
tried fixing it, the link of images show in my logcat but it fails to load inside the imageview

Comment: What is the value of `desName` inside `.whereEqualTo("package_name", desName)`?

Comment: That's the destination's name, desName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
I can see the link of the images in the logcat but it always shows 'Load Failed for the firebase link

Comment: And what does `intent.getStringExtra("name")` return? What is the exact value?

Comment: In this case its "Baguio City", the activity is a Destination Details holder so it changes depending on which recyclerview card is clicked. Sorry if I can't explain it clearly, but I edited my code  I hope you can help me on why it won't load the links thank you

Comment: Show us the `package_name` field inside the document.